# How to assign object's parents to QObjectList?

Tags: c++, qt, oop, inheritance

I can use this code for the assign children.

```
QObjectList boxes = this->children();
```

But i can't use this code.

```
QObjectList boxes = ui->checkBox_2->parent();
```

How can i obtain parents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default method to get parents so you have to iterate using the `parent()` method:

```cpp
QObjectList parents(QObject *qobject){
    if(!qobject)
        return {};
    QObjectList parents;
    const QObject *o = qobject;
    while (QObject *q = o->parent()) {
        parents.push_back(q);
        o = q;
    }
    return parents;
}
```

```
QObjectList boxes = parents(ui->checkBox_2);
```